# how to get id from notes[] array present inside Getnote.vue and based on that ID how to update a particular card?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, axios

I have some cards in my dashboard and in the dashboard I am getting some cards which contains title and description of the card, which I am getting from backend(axios.js).Upto display section i am getting, but in my case i want to update a particular card, when i click on any card the update popup card is coming. when i click on any card it opens popup card  this card purpose is to update the content based on the card id(card details stored inside notes[] array in Getnote.vue),Here my question is How to get that particular card id when user clicks on card and how to connect this thing to the back end Api for update the particular note. please help me to fix this issue

`Updatenote.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="updatecard-notes">
    <form class="updatecard-container" @submit.prevent="handleSubmit" id="update-id">
        <input name="title" id="name-in" v-model="title" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="off" />
        <textarea name="content" id="text-in" v-model="description" placeholder="Take a note..." autocomplete="off"></textarea>
        <Icon />
        <button @click="updateNotes()" type="submit">Close</button>
    </form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../../service/User'
import Icon from '../../components/pages/Icon.vue'
export default {
    name: 'Updatenote',
    components: {
        Icon
    },
    data() {
        return {
            id:'',
            title:'',
            description:''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateNotes: function() {
            const updateData ={
                id:this.id,
                title:this.title,
                description:this.description
            };
            service.userUpdateNote(updateData).then(response => {
                console.log("update",response);
                localStorage.setItem('token',response.data.token);
                this.notes.push(...response.data);
            })
        },
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.updatecard-container {
    /* width: 100px; */
    padding: 4px 10px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    /* margin-left: 200px; */
    margin-bottom: -200px;
    margin-top: -160px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 620px;
    height: 150px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #e0dede;
    /* margin-left: 731px; */
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

form textarea {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    resize: none;
}

form input {
    width: 90%;
    border: none;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

form button {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    right: 25px;
    bottom: 10px;
    background: white;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 36px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
</style>
```

`User.js`

```
import AxiosService from '../service/axios';
const axios = new AxiosService()
export default{
    userRegister(data){
        return axios.postData('/register', data);
    },
    userLogin(data){
        return axios.postData("/login",data);
    },
    userForgotPassword(data){
        return axios.postData("/auth/sendPasswordResetLink",data);
    },
    userResetPassword(data){
        return axios.postData("/auth/resetPassword",data);
    },
    userCreateNote(data){
        return axios.postData("/notes",data);
    },
    userGetNote(){
        return axios.getData("/notes");
    },
    userUpdateNote(id, data){
        console.log("ID: ",id);
        return axios.putData(`/notes/${id}`, data);
    }
}
```

`axios.js`

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.baseURL=process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_URL
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token');


export default class AxiosService{

    postData(url, data){
        return axios.post(url, data).then(response =>{
            return response;
        }).catch(error=>{
            return error;
        })
    }

    getData(url){
        return axios.get(url).then(response =>{
            return response;
        }).catch(error=>{
            return error;
        })
    }

    putData(url, data){
        return axios.put(url, data).then(response=>{
            return response;
        }).catch(error=>{
            return error;
        })
    }
}
```

`Getnotes.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-notes">
    <div class="carddisplay-container" v-for="note in notes" :key="note.data">
        <div class="carddisplay" @click="togglePopup()">
            <h3>{{note.title}}</h3>
            <p>{{note.description}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carddisplay-icons">
            <Icon />
            <button class="card-button" type="button" v-if="flag" @click="handleSubmit();ToggleButton();">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cardupdate-popup" id="popup">
        <Updatenote />
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../../service/User'
import Icon from '../../components/pages/Icon.vue'
import Updatenote from '../../components/pages/Updatenote.vue'
export default {
    name: 'Getnote',
    components: {
        Icon, Updatenote
    },
    data() {
        return {
            flag: true,
            notes:[{
                id:1,
                title: 'notes',
                description: 'display notes'
            },],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ToggleButton(){
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        async handleSubmit() {
            service.userGetNote().then(response => {
                this.notes.push(...response.data);
            })
        },
        togglePopup(){
            var popup=document.getElementById('popup');
            popup.classList.toggle('active');
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "@/SCSS/Getnote.scss";
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, pass `note.id` in the method and then handle it in to update the card.

Comment: Hello, @YashMaheshwari , Actually it's too much confusing where to and how to write the note.id..please infom me.

Comment: Your question is quite confusing, UpdateNote will be displayed if a user wants to update the cart information, right? If so then pass the note.id as a prop to updateCard and then  use that id to make the axios request.

Comment: Hi thanks for your information @YashMaheshwari , But how to pass note.id prop and how to use that prop for making request for axios

Answer (score 0):

In `GetNotes.vue` create a property in the data option, which will track the currently clicked card using the id and then pass that id to the `UpdateNote` component.

`GetNotes.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-notes">
    <div class="carddisplay-container" v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id">
        <div class="carddisplay" @click="togglePopup(note.id)">
            <h3>{{note.title}}</h3>
            <p>{{note.description}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carddisplay-icons">
            <Icon />
            <button class="card-button" type="button" v-if="flag" @click="handleSubmit();ToggleButton();">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cardupdate-popup" id="popup">
        <Updatenote :cardId="clickedCard"/>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../../service/User'
import Icon from '../../components/pages/Icon.vue'
import Updatenote from '../../components/pages/Updatenote.vue'
export default {
    name: 'Getnote',
    components: {
        Icon, Updatenote
    },
    data() {
        return {
            flag: true,
            notes:[{
                id:1,
                title: 'notes',
                description: 'display notes'
            },],
            clickedCard: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ToggleButton(){
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        async handleSubmit() {
            service.userGetNote().then(response => {
                this.notes.push(...response.data);
            })
        },
        togglePopup(id){
            var popup=document.getElementById('popup');
            popup.classList.toggle('active');
            this.clickedCard = id;
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "@/SCSS/Getnote.scss";
</style>
```

In Updatenote component use that id to make the api call. Here the `cardId` will contain the id of currently clicked card.

`Updatenote.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="updatecard-notes">
    <form class="updatecard-container" @submit.prevent="handleSubmit" id="update-id">
        <input name="title" id="name-in" v-model="title" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="off" />
        <textarea name="content" id="text-in" v-model="description" placeholder="Take a note..." autocomplete="off"></textarea>
        <Icon />
        <button @click="updateNotes()" type="submit">Close</button>
    </form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../../service/User'
import Icon from '../../components/pages/Icon.vue'
export default {
    name: 'Updatenote',
    components: {
        Icon
    },
    props: ['cardId'],
    data() {
        return {
            title:'',
            description:''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateNotes: function() {
            const updateData ={
                id:this.cardId,
                title:this.title,
                description:this.description
            };
            service.userUpdateNote(updateData).then(response => {
                console.log("update",response);
                localStorage.setItem('token',response.data.token);
                this.notes.push(...response.data);
            })
        },
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
...........
</style>
```